# Spivak Problem 3-23

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The problem reads, with $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $B \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ for some $n, m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$:

*Let $C \subset A \times B$ be a set of content $0$. Let $A' \subset A$ be the set of all $x \in A$ such that $C_x \equiv \{y \in B : (x, y) \in C\}$ does* not *have content $0$. Show that $A'$ is a set of measure $0$.*

Intuitively this sort of makes sense; if $A'$ was, for example, a closed interval, and every $C_x$ for $x \in A'$ included a closed interval, then you might, for example, have a closed rectangle in $C$, which would make $C$ have nonzero measure.

**My attempt at a solution:** $C$ has content $0$, so its boundary has content $0$, so $\chi_C$ is integrable over $A \times B$. By Fubini's Theorem, we have $\int_A \mathscr{U} = \int_A \mathscr{L}$, where $\mathscr{U}(x)$ and $\mathscr{L}(x)$ are the lower and upper integrals of the restriction of $\chi_C$ to $x$ (which is $\chi_{C_x}$). Thus, $\int_A \mathscr{U} - \mathscr{L} = 0$, and since $\mathscr{U} - \mathscr{L} \geq 0$, we have that

$$X \equiv \{x \in A : \mathscr{U}(x) - \mathscr{L}(x) \neq 0\} = \{x \in A : \mathscr{U}(x) > \mathscr{L}(x)\}$$

has measure $0$.

If $p \in X$, then $\chi_{C_p}$ is not integrable, so suppose $C_p$ has content $0$. Then the boundary of $C_p$ has content $0$, so $\chi_{C_p}$ is integrable, which is a contradiction. So $C_p$ does not have content $0$. This proves that $X \subset A'$.

**Where I'm stuck: I want to show that if $C_p$ does not have content $0$, then $C_p$ also does not have measure $0$. But I can't figure out how.** I think it may have something to do with the fact that $C$ has content $0$.

Suppose this is true. Then if $x \in A' - X$, we have that $C_x$ does not have content $0$, and thus (by what I need to prove) does not have measure $0$. But $x \not \in X$ implies that $\mathscr{U} = \mathscr{L}$, so $\int_B \chi_{C_x}$ exists and is non-zero since $C_x$ has nonzero measure. But then $\int_B \chi_{C_x} = \mathscr{L}(x) \neq 0$. Since $C$ has content $0$, we know from previous exercises and Fubini's Theorem that

$$0 = \int_{A \times B} \chi_C = \int_A \mathscr{L},$$

so since $\mathscr{L} \geq 0$, we have that $Y \equiv \{x \in A: \mathscr{L}(x) \neq 0\}$ has measure $0$. So we've shown that $A' - X \subset Y$.

Finally, we have that $A' = X \cup (A' - X) \subset X \cup Y$, which has measure $0$ since $\mu(X) = \mu(Y) = 0$. Thus $A'$ has measure $0$.

So how might I begin to prove my missing part? Or is this even the right thing to prove? Just a hint is all I'm looking for.

**EDIT:** Spivak's definitions of measure $0$ and content $0$ that I'm using are the following:

If $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, then $A$ has measure $0$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is a *countable* cover $\{U_i\}_1^\infty$ of $A$ by closed rectangles such that $\sum_1^\infty v(U_i) < \epsilon$, where $v$ is $n$-dimensional volume. Content $0$ is the same thing, except with a *finite* cover instead of a countable cover.

So content $0$ $\implies$ measure $0$, but not vice versa.

Comment: I shared Spivak's definitions of content $0$ and measure $0$ for clarification.

Comment: if $x \in A - X$ then  $ ∫BχCx $